# How to write a unit test for a function that accesses a global dictionary created from a csv file?

Tags: python, unit-testing, global-variables

I have a process_persons() Python function that accesses a global dictionary as follows:

```
def process_persons():
    for k, v in person_dict.items():
        # do some processing

def main():

    global person_dict        
    person_dict = {}
    reader = csv.reader(open('person_file.csv', 'r'))
    for row in reader:
        key = (row[0], row[1])
        person_dict[key] = row[2]
```

I have written a unit test like this:

```
def test_process_persons(self):
    process_persons()
    # assert that the processing is done right!
```

But i get the error: NameError: global name 'person_dict' is not defined. Any help is appreciated.

Please note that I cannot change the methods' signatures that i am testing!

Answer (score 1):

> `NameError: global name 'person_dict' is not defined`

Well, that's because you didn't define it. How is it supposed to know what it is? You say `person_dict[key] = row[2]` but that doesn't automatically make it a dictionary. You have to initialise it with a value, e.g.

```
person_dict = {}
```

Which says it's an empty dictionary.

There is also no need for the `global` declaration. You're executing this as the top level of the file (i.e. not inside a function or a class) so it can be worked with normally.

Comment: Made some changes to my code. Replaced `if __name__=='__main__':` with `def main()` and added `person_dict = {}`.

Comment: @Malgi `def main` is fine but put `person_dict = {}` outside, like what Tobias did. Drop the `global` stuff, you don't need it, and it's generally bad practice.

Comment: Tobias's solution does not work because when we call `process_persons()` inside the unit test `test_process_persons()` the `person_dict` is empty and the CSV file has not yet stored in it

Comment: Ah, I see what you're talking about. Are you calling `main()` from your test then? In that case it probably shouldn't be called `main`, rather `initialise_person_dict` or something. Or don't put it in a function at all, but also not under `if __name__ == '__main__'` because that will only work when you run the module directly.

Comment: Actually my actual `main()` is not that much simple. It has some input parameters that specify the path to the `person_file`.  So, If I put it in a function or call the 'main()' from my test, I should know those parameters and pass them to that function or `main()`. I think there is no way than removing the global dictionary `person_dict`, and changing the `process_persons()` to 'process_persons(person_dict)' :/

Comment: That's fine, just call `initialise_person_dict` from both `main` and your tests. Or just take the initialisation outside of any function so that it runs when you import/run the module, that may be fine for your use case. Having said that, avoiding globals is often good too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's quite literally undefined. Please try replacing `global person_dict` with:

```
person_dict = {}
```

Comment: Made some changes to my code. Replaced `if __name__=='__main__':` with `def main():` and added `person_dict = {}`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what your're trying to achive but I would probably do something like this given that the signature of the function under test is frozen.

```
def process_persons():
    for k, v in person_dict.items():
        # do some processing

person_dict = {}
if __name__ == '__main__':
    reader = csv.reader(open('person_file.csv', 'r'))
    for row in reader:
        key = (row[0], row[1])
        person_dict[key] = row[2]
```

You need to define the person_dict somewhere. Stating that it is global does not  define it. `global` is used when you want to assign to a variable that has been defined on module level from within a function. If you did not specify `global`, a new, local, variable would be created in the function that would shadow the global variable. Then, when the function exits, your newly created variable would go out of scope, be garbage collected and forgotten about to no use.

Now that you have the person_dict defined on the module level you can simply assign to it from your test code before calling `process_persons` to vary the input data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have made some changes to my code. Replaced if `__name__=='__main__':` with `def main():` and added `person_dict = {}`. What do you think now?

Comment: Your solution does not work because when we call `process_persons()` inside the unit test `test_process_persons()` the `person_dict` is empty and the CSV file has not yet stored in it.

Comment: It all comes down to what you want to test I guess. Is it the functionality in `process_persons`, the functionality in `main`, or both together? To see the data read in your new `main` function from `process_persons` you would have to move the declaration of `person_dict` to the module level. Otherwise it won't be accessible from `process_persons`. Now from your test you can first call `main` followed by `process_persons`.